# How to terminate process when home button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

When the iphone home button is pressed, it will only hide the user interface but any process currently running will keep on running at the background. I find that if the process is still running, when i activate the app again, the splash screen will be displayed for a long time until the process is completes before it display the main page of the app. Is there a way to terminate the processes when the home button is pressed?

1) For example, if I have a for loop and before the loop finishes, the home button is pressed, is there a way to terminate the loop?

2) What if instead of a loop, its a delegate waiting for the sdk function to finish the process.
eg. After calling UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save an image, didFinishSavingWithError will be called when it finish saving.  Can i terminate the saving process whe the home button is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) The concept of long lasting loops in main thread is bad. They stops the application responsibility. So, put that loop in back thread, and inside the loop check global variable that you have set in main thread when applicatioResignActive happens

Answer (score 6):

You can try adding a new row in the **info.plist** of your application and select **"Application does not run in background"** or write **"UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend"**

Answer (score 2):

1. Do as Aluminum said.
2. Not to do 1, but add the following method to the app delegate

   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

and do something in the method like exit(0)